# How to pass-by-reference from Swift to C library

Tags: c, swift

I am creating a cross-platform library for Windows and macOS that is written in C, and I need to pass a variable by reference. How do I define the function in C so that it can receive a variable passed by reference, and how do I call the function in Swift?

For example, if I were to define a function in my C library like:

```
int sayBye(const char* greetingString){
    greetingString = "bye";
    return 0;
}
```

and call it in Swift like:

```
var greeting: String = "hello"
let responseCode = sayBye(greeting)
print(greeting)
```

I want the print statement to output "bye".

Constraints: "bye" cannot be returned in the return statement.

In short, I want to modify the contents of the string "greeting" after it has been passed by reference to a C-function.

Note: I'm not sure if, in the code above, I am defining the C function correctly or if I am calling it correctly in swift, and I am open to recommendations.

Comment: Pedantic note: C does not have pass-by-reference

Comment: C functions are exclusively pass-by-value.  There is no pass-by-reference.  If you want a function to be able to change a local variable of the caller, then you must provide it a pointer to that variable.  Dunno how to do that in Swift.

Comment: The problem with your code as it is, is that C doesn't really support pass by reference, you have to *emulate* it by passing a pointer to the variable you want to pass by reference. For pointer variables that means you have to pass a pointer *to the pointer*. With the code as shown, since the pointer passed to the function is passed by value, the assignment only modify the local variable, the copy you have in the function. The only solution is to change the contents of the memory where the pointer is pointing, with e.g. `strcpy`, which is kind of a show-stopper if the contents is constant.

Comment: You want to modifiy the contents of a `const char*`? You cannot.

Comment: Have a look at [Using Imported C Functions in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_functions_in_swift).

Comment: `const char **`?

Comment: thanks @DavidCullen that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Found something that worked.

In the C library:

```
int sayBye(const char** greetingString){
    *greetingString = "bye";
    return 0;
}
```

Called in Swift:

```
var greeting = ("hello" as NSString).utf8String
let responseCode = sayBye(&greeting)
let stringFromPointer = String.init(cString: greeting!)

print(stringFromPointer)
```